# How do I create a new playlist when all the options are greyed out?

Tags: itunes, macos, data-synchronization, external-disk

I'm running iTunes 11.1.5 under Mavericks 10.9.2. Because I have a very large music collection I keep it on an external drive. I have six recorded lectures I'd like to sync with my iPad. How do I create a new playlist based on the recordings on the external drive. I know it can be done because I've done it before years ago but have forgotten how.

Yes, I too wish iTunes were more coherent and less convoluted.

Comment: It isn't clear to me which options are greyed out based on the question. Are you talking about `File > New... > Playlist`?

Comment: Yes, exactly that. File > Playlist; File > Playlist from Selection; File > Smart Playlist…; File > Playlist Folder. All four of them are in grey and are currently not selectable.

Comment: Yes, exactly that. File > Playlist; File > Playlist from Selection; File > Smart Playlist…; File > Playlist Folder. All four of them are in grey and are currently not selectable. My purpose is to create a new playlist with the six new lectures. Then mark this new playlist for syncing. Then initiate syncing of marked playlists to my iPad.

Comment: are they greyed out in the menu that appears when you click the + in the bottom left corner of iTunes?